# How do I set an image to display from a dropdown menu option?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a form that displays a movie poster when you select which movie you'd like to see. I wrote a function but I'm new to javascript and something isn't working correctly.

Thanks for any help provided.

**JS**

```
function setMovie() {
  var img = document.getElementById("movimg");
  var value = img.options[img.selectedIndex].value;
  var selected = document.getElementById("selectedMovie");
  selected.src = this.value;
  return false;
}
document.getElementById("movieList").onChange = setMovie();
```

**HTML**

```
<select id="movimg" onChange="setMovie(this)">
  <option value="null.png">Select a movie!</option>
  <option value="bvs.jpg">Batman vs. Superman</option>
  <option value="tjb.jpg">The Jungle Book</option>
  <option value="tgf.jpg">The Godfather</option>
  <option value="tpb.jpg">The Princess Bride</option>
  <br>
</select>
<img src="" id="selectedMovie" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were referencing `movieList`, an id that wasn't there. You also did not need to return false in your function.

```js
var select_box = document.getElementById("movimg"),
    image_box = document.getElementById("selectedMovie");

function setMovie() {
  var value = select_box.options[select_box.selectedIndex].value;
  image_box.src = this.value;
}

select_box.addEventListener("change", setMovie);
```

```html
<select id="movimg">
        <option value="null.png">Select a movie!</option>
        <option value="bvs.jpg">Batman vs. Superman</option>
        <option value="tjb.jpg">The Jungle Book</option>
        <option value="tgf.jpg">The Godfather</option>
        <option value="tpb.jpg">The Princess Bride</option>
</select> 
<img src="" id="selectedMovie"/>
```

Comment: Thanks man. movieList existed at one point but i must have missed it :/ thank you though!

Comment: If you're satisfied with my answer, can you accept it?

Answer (score 0):

You can just change your function to this:

```
 function setMovie(){
    document.getElementById("selectedMovie").src = document.getElementById("movimg").value;
    }
```